# Ошибки mysqli_fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему выбивает ошибки и как их устранить? Благодарю заранее.

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www1/znannya.o3.ua/okk/views/feed_panel.php on line 69

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www1/znannya.o3.ua/okk/views/feed_panel.php on line 74

```
            while($table = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // go through each row that was returned in $result
            if($table[0] != "workers")
            {
                echo "<tr><p>"; echo("<td>". substr($table[0], 0, -3). "<BR>"); echo "</p></td>";   // print the table that was returned on that row.

            }
            $count = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(feedback) + COUNT(feedback_1) FROM `$table[0]`");
            while($cout = mysqli_fetch_array($count))
            {
                echo "<p>"; echo("<td>". $cout[0]. "<BR>"); echo "</p></td>"; 
            }
            $countt = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT COUNT(explanatory_1) + COUNT(explanatory_2) + COUNT(explanatory_3) + COUNT(explanatory_4) FROM `$table[0]`");
            while($couts = mysqli_fetch_array($countt))
            {
                echo "<p>"; echo("<td>". $couts[0]. "<BR>"); echo "</p></tr></td>"; 
            }
        }
```

Ошибки в данных строках даёт:

> while($cout = mysqli_fetch_array($count))
>
> while($couts = mysqli_fetch_array($countt))

Comment: *попытался исправлять - не вышло. Может кто-то подскажет как пофиксить? Только не кидайтесь тапочками :(

Comment: я так понимаю что `mysqli_query` возвращает `false` в случае ошибки, вполне вероятно что это ваш случай, проверьте после каждого вызова этой функции наличие ошибок `var_dump(mysqli_error_list($link))`
Ну и по хорошему из этого нужно сделать нормальную проверку после каждого вызова, чтобы такое потом не случалось после того как отвалилась DB или еще чего

Comment: @zippp что-то подобное выдало:
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["errno"]=> int(1054) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "42S22" ["error"]=> string(41) "Unknown column 'feedback' in 'field list'" } }

Comment: ну и вперед - в запросе `COUNT(feedback)` ссылается на колонку, которой нет в таблице `$table[0]`. Т.е скорей всего в `$table[0]` неправильные данные, распечатывайте что в ней

Comment: @zippp $table[0] - это названия таблиц. В них есть feedback строка - там текст (нужно вывести количество этих строк), оно вроде выводит - но выводит эту ошибку. Что может быть не так?

Comment: Андрей, все просто - распечатайте название таблицы. Если там неправильное название, то это причина проблемы, если правильное, то залезьте в базу данных и посмотрите есть ли в этой таблице колонка `feedback`

Comment: @zippp Может ли это быть из-за этого? if($table[0] != "workers") - я таким способом не вывожу данную таблицу в никнеймы, а в других запросах данной строки нету (не знаю как указать)

Comment: Андрей, распечатайте всю строку выборки `"SELECT COUNT(feedback) + COUNT(feedback_1) FROM $table[0]"` и думаю все будет понятно. Ошибка ведь ясно указывает, что `"Unknown column 'feedback' in 'field list'"` т.е такой колонки нет в таблице, следовательно или запрос из не той таблицы или в таблице нет такой колонки